# VT100.Translation key binding in UXTerm

Tags: xterm, clipboard, x-resources

Is it possible to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> for copy and pasting to and from clipboard in `UXterm` in a similar fashion to `XTerm`, a la

```
xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \
      Shift <KeyPress> Insert: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
      Ctrl Shift <Key>V:    insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

I changed `xterm` to `uxterm` to no effect. If `UXTerm` is just a wrapper, there has to be a way, right?

Motivation: Since my rig is a chromebook, it has no <kbd>Ins</kbd> that I can make use of (along with a bunch of other keys; all redundant keys have already been mapped to other essential keys like <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, etc.. `UXTerm` also doesn't recognize three-finger tap  as a middle  click, so I'm left with no means of pasting in UXterm.

Answer (score 1):

Apparent all I needed to do is simply to get rid of `xterm` in the configuration:

```
*VT100.Translations: #override \
      Shift <KeyPress> Insert: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
      Ctrl Shift <Key>V:    insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

This, however, would apply to all X11 apps, so hopefully it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 1):

That first line needs a *newline*.  Rather than

```
    xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \
```

if you had used

```
    xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \n\
```

then the comment on the first line would not have extended into the "second line", making it ineffective.  If that were fixed, of course, you might have other resource-settings not shown which could interfere with this.

The xterm [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Custom-Key-Bindings) gives a few examples of custom bindings.

The behavior of triple-click is configurable (see [**`on3Clicks`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:on3Clicks) resource).

Changing "xterm" to "uxterm" in the resource-settings would not help because **`uxterm`** is a script.  The application name (usually "xterm") is set by the actual executable.